# How to insert records into a Nested HashMap?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, nested, hashmap

I want to create a nested `HashMap` of:

```
var myHashMap = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, int>>();
```

And I want to insert records into the inner `HashMap`, I find myself needing to instantiate the inner `HashMap` if the key doesn't exist:

```
var myHashMap = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, int>>();
var outerStringValue = "ABC";
var innerStringValue = "XYZ";
var innerInt = 45;

if (!myHashMap.containsKey(outerStringValue) {
    var innerHashMap = new HashMap<String, int>();
    innerHashMap.put(innerStringValue, innerInt);
    myHashMap.put(outerStringValue, innerHashMap);
} else {
    myHashMap.get(outerStringValue).put(innerStringValue, innerInt);
}
```

Is there a better way to do this without instantiating a new `innerHashMap` for each unique `myHashMap` (the outer `HashMap`) key?

Answer (score 5):

You can use Java 8 method [`computeIfAbsent()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent(K,java.util.function.Function)). It expects a *key*, a *function* that will be triggered and will generate a value if the given key is not present in the map.

Note that this method will return a value that is currently associated with the given key, i.e. a previously existing inner *map*, or a *map* generated as a result of the method execution.

```
Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> nestedMap = new HashMap<>();

nestedMap.computeIfAbsent(outerKey,k -> new HashMap<>())
    .put(innerKey, someValue);
```

*Also note:*

- It's not possible to use primitives like `int` as a generic type parameters. Generic parameter should be an object (*for more information,* [*see*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html))

Comment: If `outerKey` is present, `computeIfAbsent()` will simply return the `HashMap` that's already stored under that key instead of computing a new one. This does everything that OP's logic did.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Would you mind writing out the full argument syntax for computeIfAbsent? I'm actually writing in a java variant that doesn't support 'k ->' syntax, so I'll need to write it out the long way. (Sorry I'm a noob at this - still learning). 

Thanks!

Comment: @miikey722 That code will compile and execute successfully (*if you define variables like* `outerKey`). Lambda expressions are supported since Java 8. I see Java 10 local variable type inference (`var`) in your code, that means that your JDK version is at least 10.  If you are not familiar with lambda expressions, I suggest you to start with this [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html).

Comment: To add some clarity: I'm reading through the guide and it says that the language does not support the syntax <? super TYPE>.

Which is exactly what computeIfAbsent uses :( Hence why k -> new hashMap is throwing an exception.

Comment: @miikey722 You can run this [demo](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/qQL) online.

Comment: Thanks. Your solution definitely works for Java. I'm actually writing in a language called Gosu, which is based on Java. And apparently gosu doesn't support <? super TYPE> generics syntax. Unfortunate :(

Comment: @miikey722 Most of the functional interfaces in Java are making use of wildcard generics. It's hard to suggest a workaround for this JVM language. You've perplexed me, I have no knowledge on Gosu.

Comment: @miikey722 Just as an experiment, try this [code](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/qQM).  I do not consider anonymous inner class as an option, but just to find out whether it runs.

Comment: @miikey722 As an alternative, you might try `Table` from the Guava library as a replacement for the nested map https://guava.dev/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/HashBasedTable.html